# Tuple of an arbitrary, but compile-time-known number of types

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Say I have a type that is parameterized by another integral POD type:

```
template< size_t N >
struct MyFoo { /* ... */ };
```

With it, it is possible to have a tuple of them:

```
typedef std::tuple< MyFoo< 1 >, MyFoo< 2 >, MyFoo< 3 > > Foo3;
```

But now, I want to have a type "`Foo< N >`", where `N` is a `constexpr`. One way to achieve something resembling a `Foo< N >` would be:

```
template< size_t N >
struct Foos;

template<> struct Foos< 1 >{ typedef std::tuple< MyFoo< 1 > > type; };
template<> struct Foos< 2 >{ typedef std::tuple< MyFoo< 1 >, MyFoo< 2 > > type; };
/* continue with this.... */
```

E.e. specialize it manually for each N I want. Is there a more generic way to do this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template<std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
struct MakeFoos : MakeFoos<N - 1, N, Is...>
{
};

template<std::size_t... Is>
struct MakeFoos<0, Is...>
{
    using type = std::tuple<MyFoo<Is>...>;
};

template<std::size_t N>
struct Foos
{
    using type = typename MakeFoos<N>::type;
};
```

To get your tuple write `Foos<3>::type`.

Comment: Nice! And is there a way to do this withoud variadic templates? I'm kind of stuck with the old standard...

Comment: @Sh4pe, Boost has some support in that area.

Comment: @Sh4pe if you can't use C++11 then you have to do it the way you were already doing it or use preprocessor macros.

Comment: @Sh4pe, Wait, if you're in the old standard, how are you using `std::tuple`?

Answer (score 3):

You need some machinery to build a sequence of integers from 1 to N. The rest is pretty straightforward:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <tuple>

// to generate a sequence of indices:

template<size_t... Ns>
struct indices {
    typedef indices< Ns..., sizeof...( Ns ) > next;
};

template<size_t N>
struct make_indices {
    typedef typename make_indices< N - 1 >::type::next type;
};

template<>
struct make_indices< 0 > {
    typedef indices<> type;
};

// create a sequence and expand it inside a typedef

template<size_t N>
struct MyFoo {};

template< size_t N >
struct Foos {

    template<typename>
    struct Helper;

    template<size_t... Ns>
    struct Helper<indices<Ns...>> {
        typedef std::tuple< MyFoo<Ns>... > type;
    };

    typedef typename
    Helper< typename make_indices<N>::type >::type type;
};
```

[Live demo.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/727b895ba7fae4a1)

Comment: C++14 has this machinery, btw.

Comment: Nice! And is there a way to do this withoud variadic templates? I'm kind of stuck with the old standard...

Comment: @Sh4pe That would be the way you did it yourself. Libraries like boost can hide the specializations stuff away for you, using preprocessor tricks. You can look at Loki TypeList library to see how things are implemented, too.

Comment: Note that my code builds a sequence from 0 to N-1. Play around a little to make 1..N.

Comment: @SebastianRedl what do you mean?

Comment: @soandos He means [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence).